# jQuery UI - Autocomplete generated inline style override?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I'm using [jQuery Autocomplete plugin](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) which, generates following markup when suggestions show up.

```
<ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" role="listbox" aria-activedescendant="ui-active-menuitem" style="z-index: 16; width: 1355px; position: relative; top: -1615px; left: 40px; display: none; ">
    <li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem">
        <a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">java</a>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem">
        <a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">javascript</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

My understanding is, it's using the [UI Position](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Position) plugin to position it relative to the input field. But inside generated `style="z-index: 16; width: 1355px; position: relative; top: -1615px; left: 40px; display: none; "`, width is much longer than my input field.
Since this is inline styles added by the module, I can not override this using `ui-autocomplete` selector. Any ideas?

Comment: Note: width of my input field is `1140px`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `!important` method in css: e.g.

```
.ui-autocomplete {
    width:200px !important;
}
```

Comment: Awesome fix!  I had the same issue where the jQuery UI (for tabs) injected an inline style width and on IE it was always pixel based (all other browsers were percent based and was correct value).  With your proposed '!important' flag in my CSS, IE works like all other browsers... thanks!

Comment: @Jeach Good to know it helped you. You should how ever think this method of the last posible option. Because it can put you in one of the most painful css debugs.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!  But out of curiosity, do you (or anyone else) know why on IE, they inject a pixel value (which is too wide, to make things worse) and all other browsers, they inject a percentage?

Comment: Maybe IE cant figure out to hit 100%. E.g: `width = 950`; 25% of 950 is `237.5`. Maybe IE will try to render this as `238` and maybe as `237`. I don't know this is just an assumption. But ether way you will have `2` pixel to spare.