# jQuery UI Menu Positioning Issues

Tags: css, jquery-ui, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to use jQuery UI to create a dropdown menu on a site that I'm working on. It looks okay at first glance, but the starting position of the nested `ul` elements seem to be blocking the next link in the menu. The blue box is what appears when I hover over the nested `ul` in Firebug and prevents hovering over "Link 2" How can I move this align this with the actual menu? Thank you!

[image: Menu]

The sub-links in grey work fine.

```
<div id="nav">
<ul>
<li>Link 1
<ul>
...
</ul>
</li>
<li>Link 2</li>
<li>Link 3</li>
</ul>
</div>

#nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    float:right;
}

#nav ul li ul {
    position:absolute;
    width: 200px;
}

#nav ul li ul li {
    display: block;
    position:relative;
    top:40px;
    left:-165px;
}
```

Comment: do you have a jsfiddle of this?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out jQuery UI was generating some inline styles in an attempt to correctly position the dropdown menu.

```
<ul ... style="display: none; top: 84px; left: 913px;" aria-hidden="true">
```

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8071991/jquery-ui-autocomplete-generated-inline-style-override) with a similar issue. I added the following style to my stylesheet and it works now:

```
.ui-menu { top: auto !important; left:auto !important; }
```